# How to mock Angular's 'LocationChangeListener' interface with Jasmine?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

I'm having a bad time trying to mock Angular's **LocationChangeListener** interface, using Jasmine.

This is what my code do:

```js
      onPopState(fn: LocationChangeListener): void {
        this.platformLocation.onPopState((ev: LocationChangeEvent): void => {
    
        ... here I do the stuff I actually want to test ...
    
      }
    }
```

So basically, I'm trying to call *onPopState* with a *LocatioNChangeListener*, so I can test all the logic inside the function.
I already mocked the *LocationChangeEvent*:

```js
      const locationChangeEventMock: LocationChangeEvent = {
        type: 'typemock',
        state: 1,
      };
```

But all my efforts to mock **LocationChangeListener** are in vain... Is it actually possible? Due to TypeScript 'issues' with interfaces?

**Edit**: after some debugging, it looks like *ev: LocationChangeEvent* doesn't comes from *LocationChangeListener* (apparently), so I need to, somehow, trigger *LocationChangeEvent*?

By now, I sorted it doing some code refactor: extracting the code I wanted to a method, and then calling that method... but still curious how to test this.

Comment: How do you use `fn` inside your method?

Comment: At the end of the method, like this: `fn(ev);`. What is really important for me is to be able to work with the `LocationChangeEvent`, as it's what I work with inside the method, so I truly need a workable mock of `LocationChangeListener` that calls the `LocationChangeEvent` mock.

Comment: I have added an answer and created an example of mock. https://codesandbox.io/s/fomfx
You can check it in the Typescript playground. This mock is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you can pass an empty cb-function as a mock like this:

```
function onPopState(fn: LocationChangeListener): void {}

onPopState((val)=>{console.log('some logic', val)});

// OR
function mockFunc(val: LocationChangeEvent){
  console.log(val);
}

onPopState(mockFunc);
```

It should be valid.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I think I'm missing something, as I can't see how to use this on the test: if in my test I'm calling `service.onPopState()` (`service.onPopState(mockFunc)` in this case), so I can then check the functionality inside the method, I can't pass from `this.platformLocation.onPopState((ev: LocationChangeEvent): void => {` point. It looks like `LocationChangeEvent` is not properly set.